# Grazing angle translucency bug artifacts?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, transparency, lighting

Hwelp wtf is this guys? It appears only at low angle and with rough translucent material

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, what bug do you mean exactly? That the light is shining through a material which has the _Transmission_ set to 1 (so it is transmissive)? Or the hard shadow that comes from the fact that the object is open to the (in the image) left side so that the sun lamp can directly shine inside and the edge of the backside throws a shadow, because a rough transmissive material does not let as much light through as an open hole? Looks all perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I've added another screenshot, this grid pattern doesnt look right to me, it shouldn't be there, it also depends on the number of subdivisions

Comment: Looks a bit like you have an object inside the translucent object

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz but I don't, I appended the blend file, its simple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are facing is most likely the terminator effect. It happens mostly when there is only 1 light source that hits some of the faces at a grazing angle:
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Mtbbbc/?sorting=hot
To get rid of it, I hope the solution works for your project:
Either increase the subdivisions, this way the surface is smoother (and the faces are smaller, so it's much less visible)
Or add another light to complement the one you have.
I used a Nishita Sky with emission 0.05 and set the subdivision to 3 I can't see it anymore.

Comment: I think you're onto it. Just out of curiosity.. have you had any luck with Object Properties > Shading >  the Termination Offsets? I don't seem to be able to tweak them to a satisfactory value.